# ctrl+f5 — проблема с jquery

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть функция, которая исполняется при изменении размеров окна и при загрузке странице (тогда имитируется изменение). При нажатии на `ctrl+f5` страница перегружается, но скрипт не исполняется.

По-идее, `ctrl+f5` — это перезагрузка кэшированых элементов страницы (*если я правильно понял*), тоесть это не загрузка страницы, а совсем другое событие. Как правильно обьявить это событие? Или проблема не в этом?

---

Сам скрипт:

```
$(window).resize(function(){/*функция*/});
$(document).ready(function(){$(window).resize()})
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

странно.. добавив алерт по подсказке [[@RedMonkey](/users/5927/redmonkey)](/users/5927/redmonkey), функция заработала:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(window).resize();alert(0)})
```

Поэксперементировав, получилась работающая функция:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(window).resize();return false})
```

Я не могу понять почему, но работает.

Answer (score 1):

так функция не вызовется:

```
$(document).ready(function(){$(window).resize()})
```

Нужно:

```
$(window).resize(function(){/*функция*/});  // навешивание события на ресайз
$(document).ready(function(){function(){/*функция*/}}) // выполнение функции после загрузки страницы
```

Comment: разве не можно имитировать `resize` окна при загрузке? Но почему тогда `$(window).resize()` корректно исполняется при загрузке почти во всех браузерах?

Comment: глянул документацию - блин, реально можно так делать, а я, дурак, всегда тригеры юзал  
Сейчас потестил, у меня событие по твоему коду вызывается на ctrl+f5

Comment: @RedMonkey, в каком браузере вызывается? у меня вот в `Opera` — всё ок, а вот `Mozilla Firefox` просто не исполняет функцию, странно.

Comment: именно в мозиле и тестил, попробуй вывести алертом

Comment: действительно странно, может мозиле где что в самой функции не нравится